# PL/sql unique values output

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to to display the list of unique customer_IDs in the sales table.

after several attempts I reached to this code but there is no output and I'm not sure if its the write structure. any help please?

```
declare
  c_id int;
begin
  select max(unique(customer_ID)) into c_id from sales;
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Employee Nnumber: ' || c_id);
  end loop ;
end;
/
```

Comment: why don't you use DISTINCT instead of max(unique(customer_id))?

Comment: still new to pl/sql .. any help in appreciated

Comment: `select max(unique(customer_ID)) into c_id from sales;` will only return a **single** row.

Comment: Thank you very much.. what would if I want for an end user to insert a value in the customre_id? like&& in sql

Answer (score 1):

Based on the text of your question, my guess is that you are looking for something like

```
BEGIN
  FOR c IN (SELECT DISTINCT customer_id FROM sales)
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line( 'Customer ID: ' || c.customer_id );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Of course, you'd need to enable `dbms_output` in whatever tool you are using to see the output (`set serveroutput on;` in `SQL*Plus`).

Comment: Thank you very much.. what would if I want for an end user to insert a value in the customre_id? like&& in sql